# Python 2.7.10 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

Why is this function not working?

```
    def elo(Winner_Elo,Loser_Elo):
        max_ero = float(400)
        voitto = 1
        havio = 0
        K = 20
        odotusarvo1 = 1/(1 + (10**((Loser_Elo - Winner_Elo)/max_ero))
        odotusarvo2 = 1/(1 + (10**((Winner_Elo - Loser_Elo)/max_ero))
        elo1 = Winner_Elo + K*(voitto - odotusarvo1)
        elo2 = Loser_Elo + K*(havio - odotusarvo2)
        return elo1, elo2
```

Error:

```
File "sss.py", line 39
   odotusarvo2 = 1/(1 + (10**((Winner_Elo - Loser_Elo)/max_ero))
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The first variable 'odotusarvo1' seems to be working fine?

Comment: Count the number of parenthesis you have in your `odotusarvo1` (and 2) line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
        odotusarvo1 = 1/(1 + (10**((Loser_Elo - Winner_Elo)/max_ero))
        odotusarvo2 = 1/(1 + (10**((Winner_Elo - Loser_Elo)/max_ero))
```

do this:

```
        odotusarvo1 = 1/(1 + (10**((Loser_Elo - Winner_Elo)/max_ero)))
        odotusarvo2 = 1/(1 + (10**((Winner_Elo - Loser_Elo)/max_ero)))
```

You have unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! Working now.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some parentheses after max_ero

```
def elo(Winner_Elo,Loser_Elo):
    max_ero = float(400)
    voitto = 1
    havio = 0
    K = 20
    odotusarvo1 = 1/(1 + (10**((Loser_Elo - Winner_Elo)/max_ero)))
    odotusarvo2 = 1/(1 + (10**((Winner_Elo - Loser_Elo)/max_ero)))
    elo1 = Winner_Elo + K*(voitto - odotusarvo1)
    elo2 = Loser_Elo + K*(havio - odotusarvo2)
    return elo1, elo2
```